# Export datagridview to openoffice or libreoffice

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, ms-office

I googled about this thing but I couldn't find nothing. This is the code what I use but it works only with excel..

```
    private void Copy()
    {
        dgv.SelectAll();
        DataObject dataObj = dgv.GetClipboardContent();
        if (dataObj != null)
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);
    }

    private void exportToExcel(string filename)
    {
        Copy();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        xlexcel = new Excel.Application();
        xlexcel.Visible = true;
        xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        Excel.Range CR = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
        CR.Select();
        xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(CR, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);
        xlexcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs(filename);
        xlexcel.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;

    }
```

This is the code in the export button

```
private void btnExportMS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    sfd.Filter = "Excel Documents (*.csv)|*.csv";
    sfd.FileName = "export.csv";
    if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        exportToExcel(sfd.FileName); 
}
```

Comment: So openoffice and libreoffice failed to open the csv files?

Comment: they just can't open this file